# Parameter estimation constrained by RMSE and variance

Tags: regression, python, optimization

I have a time series y(t) of observations that can be approximated by the following linear model with unknown parameters:

$$y(t) = \alpha*X_{1}(t) + \beta*X_{2}(t) +\gamma*X_{3}(t)$$

X1, X2 and X3 are in fact outputs of an ensemble model, thus average (and consequently the RMSE) and variance can be estimated. I want to optimize the parameters while keeping the ratio RMSE/Var approx. 1.

Any tips on how I can approach the problem?

Comment: Hello, @edvh, and welcome to the site!  I am sorry, but I cannot understand your question.  Why wouldn't you want to minimize the variance of the residuals rather than setting it equal to some number?  Since RMSE/Var $\approx 1$ when RMSE and Var both $=1$, that number would appear to equal $1$... but why is that important?

Comment: Hello, @jbowman. Many thanks for the prompt response. In my area of study, one of the criteria of ensemble reliability is that the RMSE of the ensemble mean should match the square root of the ensemble variance, but they are not necessarily = 1. A reference publication about the topic: https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/hydr/15/4/jhm-d-14-0008_1.xml

Comment: In the case of the equation above, X2 is often an order of magnitude greater than X1 and X3, and it is characterized by low spread. Thus, if beta >= 0.05 or higher, one might get a very low VAR, so RMSE/Var >> 1.

Comment: So this should generate a weighted average that gets the correct mean and RMSE?

Comment: Yes. Or in other words, considering the N ensemble members, what's the optimal values of alpha, beta and gamma keeping RMSE/Var approx. 1. I certainly could do it computationally, by setting a mesh with a range of values, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way of solving it.